# jBPM 6.4 RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory + LDAP

Tags: jbpm

I have jBPM 6.4.0 configured with LDAP ( based on this tout j[BPM 6.4.0 + LDAP](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269667) ) and everything OK but as using restTemplateFactory and RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory  in my web app (Spring security with LDAP) and  i do not know how can i authorized with username and password (LDAP). Any advice or configurations? Thanks.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand your question. What exactly is working and what is not?

Comment: OK, thanks for your interested, i found the solution that using http://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html for authentication and authorization modules from the jBPM application.